# Error on INSERT QUERY

Tags: php, database, mysqli

We are trying to make a registration form but we cannot find our problem.
or connection is fine, no errors and still the query isn't parsing "gebruikersnaam" and "wachtwoord" to our sql database.

Can someone help us?

```
if(isset($_POST['submitRegistreren'])){
    $gebruikersnaam = $_POST['gebruikersnaam'];
    $wachtwoord = /*sha1*/$_POST['wachtwoord'];

    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT gebruikersnaam FROM inlog");

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        if($gebruikersnaam == $rows['gebruikersnaam']){
            echo '<br /><h2>Gebruikersnaam bestaat al!</h2>';
        }elseif($gebruikersnaam && $wachtwoord){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO inlog (gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord) VALUES(".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $gebruikersnaam).", ".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $wachtwoord).")" or die(mysqli_error());
        //  header('refresh:3;url=home.php?page=1');
            if($sql){ echo $sql;
                echo '<br /><h2>U bent succesvol geregistreerd!</h2>';
            }else{
                echo '<br /><h2>Er is iets misgegaan</h2>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<br /><h2>Geen juist gebruikersnaam en/of wachtwoord ingevoerd</h2>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove connection object `$connect` from the INSERT query values.

```
$gebruikersnaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['gebruikersnaam']);
$wachtwoord = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['wachtwoord']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO inlog (gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord) VALUES('".$gebruikersnaam."', '".$wachtwoord."')";
```

and add it where you are executing the query.

```
 if($connect,mysqli_query($sql))
```

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ...

error

Answer (score 0):

Your $sql variable is just a string, you're not actually calling mysqli_query() anywhere.

try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO inlog (gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord) VALUES(".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $gebruikersnaam).", ".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $wachtwoord).")";
if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){
    echo '<br /><h2>U bent succesvol geregistreerd!</h2>';
}else{
    echo '<br /><h2>Er is iets misgegaan</h2>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO inlog (gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord) 
VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $gebruikersnaam)."', 
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $wachtwoord)."')");
```

The problem was: $sql = mysqli_query($connect, ....